# Automatically set append attribute for newly created files/folders?

Tags: linux, rhel, xattr

I'm trying to setup a folder so that users can only create or modify files/folders in it, but not delete them. I tried the 'chattr +a' command and got different results in RHEL5.8 and RHEL6.5 respectively. I tried the following command:

```
# chattr +a /home/share
```

In RHEL5.8, the 'append' attribute is automatically set for newly created files/folders under /home/share folder, which is what I want. But it is not the case in RHEL6.5, that cause users can still remove files/folders under sub-folfers of /home/share. For example:

```
$ mkdir /home/share/test-folder
$ touch /home/share/test-folder/test-file
$ rm /home/share/test-folder/test-file
```

The file 'test-file' still can be removed.

So my question is, in RHEL6.5, how can I get the same result as what I got in RHEL5.8? or is there other solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to install a tool that list to the kernel's file notifications ([inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)). Then configure it to  execute `chattr` as soon as the files and directories are created.

The example below use `incrond` (available in Debian and Red Hat/CentOS EPEL repo), but you may want to use a tool based on [FAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor), if you use an NFS export.

```
mkdir /srv/incrontest
```

Create the file `/etc/incron.d/incrontest` with the following content:

```
      /srv/incrontest IN_CREATE chattr +a $@/$#
```

Then (re)start the dameon
    systemctl start incron

(Make sure you `systemctl enable incron` if you live in RPM world)

Voilà