# How to protect/secure the "sudo" log_input/log_output logs?

Tags: sudo, root, logs

My Chief Security Officer (CSO) want to log the activity of the privileged account (root). I know I can configure sudo to log user input (key strokes) and console/terminal output (stdout/stderr), as explained in [How to log commands within a "sudo su -"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108577/16640). But the content is always logged to a file locally. That file can easily be wiped by the root user !

I have enable logging in /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults>root log_input, log_output
Defaults iolog_dir=/var/log/sudo-io
```

or equivalent

```
root      ALL = (ALL) LOG_INPUT: LOG_OUTPUT:      ALL
```

**How to protect/secure the file from deletion ?**

Comment: I think you can use a filter with syslog-ng et choose to log to a remote machine. For the filter: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/676/Isolating_sudo_messages_from_syslog and for the remote logging: https://www.monitis.com/blog/2011/09/14/logging-to-a-remote-host-with-syslog-ng

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

**Local logging (but the root account can wipe the files one way or another)**

You can use `chattr +a` on the directory to make it *append only*. But unfortunately, this attribute is not inherited to new files and directory ([What is the effect of "chattr +a" on a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269020/16640)).

```
chattr -R +a /var/log/sudo-io
```

Then you can use a tool that use the kernel's inotify feature to set the *append only* attributes on new files and directories (See:  [Automatically set append attribute for newly created files/folders?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265635/16640)). (there is probably a timing attack here)

SELinux can certainly help confining the user privileged account here ! (`staff_u` and `sysadm_u` can't access the logs)

**Remote logging**

Unfortunately, the layout and format of the log files makes it difficult to forward using syslog (5 files per session):

```
/var/log/sudo-io
/var/log/sudo-io/seq
/var/log/sudo-io/00
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/02
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/02/stdout
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/02/log
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/02/timing
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/02/stderr
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/02/ttyout
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01/stdin
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01/stdout
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01/log
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01/timing
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01/ttyin
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01/stderr
/var/log/sudo-io/00/00/01/ttyout
```

It would be easy to write the log files to a remote server by mounting 
the directory specified by sudo's `iolog_dir` to a remote server using NFS/CIFS. The NFS exported directory would need `chattr +` as above.

Obviously, that server should be more secure so the user can't connect to that server and erase the files there :-).

Note that **sudo will refuse to run** if it can't create the log files: *sudo: unable to open /var/log/sudo-io/seq: Permission denied*

Answer (score 2):

Anything you will do locally, on the server, can be circumvented by an admin or hacker, who is determined. The only way to ensure the integrity of any log is to log them (or at least replicate them) to a remote syslog server. I am not going to go into the detail of how this is done as it is a very well known concept. If you are not aware, please search and read about `syslog-ng`. Make sure the remote syslog server, could only be accessed by the CSO's team only and not by anyone from the sysadmin team. Segregation of responsibilities is the only way to ensure against log tampering. If I were your CSO, I'd physically place the server where no operator or no sysadmin can access. Because, once you have physical access to any box, security goes out the window. My 2 cents.

Comment: You might also want to consider using rsyslog which might already be part of your distro.